# RabbitMQ / rstream : Can I choose between getting all messages or all messages since the start of the program?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, rstream

I am currently attempting to use some [RabbitMQ streams](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) for the purposes of my project

I have attempted to use the [rstream](https://github.com/qweeze/rstream) library such as recommended on the [RabbitMQ website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) in order to do so and it works to an extent but is has no documentation and I cannot get it to work as I need.

I would like to be able to be able to choose to get from an index such as the last previously processed message or from the start ( such as the [code example](https://github.com/qweeze/rstream) shows )

Currently my solution is to name the messages in a way that would include the date and then parse the names in order to know from where I need to start. This is not ideal and can cause issues if I start to accumulate many messages

How can I get the messages starting from the last received message rather than from the start ? ( if my program is restarted for what ever reason as an example )